# Linearly independence of an infinite set of functions

Tags: functional-analysis

While trying to prove that a particular integral operator is not compact (its kernel is unbounded and not square-integrable, which makes it evade most theorems on integral operators), I had to find a bounded sequence of functions that is mapped by this operator to a sequence without any converging subsequence. While constructing my counterexample, I bumped onto the following problem:

I am considering this family of functions:
$$ f_n(x) = \arctan(\frac{1}{nx}) - \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}  $$
How can I prove that ${f_1,f_2,....}$ forms a linearly independent set? I don't even know how to approach the problem. Intuitively it seems that $f_n$ has more and more high frequencies when $n\rightarrow\infty$ which makes $f_n$ out of the span of ${f_1,...,f_{n-1}}$. Any suggestions?
Thx!

Comment: you can begin with, proving, $f_1,f_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Without actually having done the calculations: a set is linearly independent iff all its finite subsets are linearly independent. Also, a set is linearly independent if it is a subset of a linearly independent set. And since every finite subset of your set of functions $f_n$ is a subset of a set of the form $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$, it suffices to show that all of these sets are linearly independent. Which could possibly be proved using induction.

Comment: Tips: 1. Replace $x$ with $1/x$. 2. Take a derivative. 3. Consider poles.

Comment: That leads to proving that the $$ 2nx^2/(n^2+x^2)^2$$ are linearly independent. The $\arctan$ is gone, but the problem is pretty much the same. Did I miss something?

Comment: One way may be to consider Taylor expansion of $f_n$ around $\infty$ with enough terms. This should lead to an invertible matrix.

Comment: @Sean Eberhard: ok now I see your point about poles: if the functions have different poles they are by construction linearly independent. In this case there is no poles on real numbers (n is a non negative integer). However, replacing x by $\sqrt{y}$ leads to a function with poles in the negative domain. I suppose that I can say this: each $2ny/(n^2 +y)^2$ has a unique pole at $y=-1/n^2$ so these functions are linearly independent. Because the functions are infinitely differentiable at 0, that forces them to be linearly independent for $x>0$. Then, using $x=y^2$, I get my result. Is that good?

Comment: That's close to what I had in mind. Let $f_n(x) = 2nx^2 / (n^2 + x^2)^2$. Then $f_n(x)$ is a rational function, so if you have a linear relation $a_1 f_1(x) + \cdots + a_n f_n(x) = 0$ which holds for infinitely many values of $x$ then it must hold for all complex values of $x$ (apart from poles). Now since $f_1$ is the only function with a pole at $i$, $a_1 = 0$, etc.

Comment: Your comment about "linearly independent for $x > 0$" doesn't make much sense I think. Linear independence is a property of the functions, not of the function values.

Comment: you're right. What I meant is the restriction of $f_n$ to $x>0$.